# How to copy a font programmatically to /System/Library/Fonts/?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to copy a font programmatically to the location /System/Library/Fonts/. I used the following coding to do this

```
NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:@/System/Library/Fonts error:&error];
```

For this I am getting the error..

```
Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 UserInfo=0x4193e0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied"
```

If I copy the font manually it ask the password first and then it copies to the location. But If I done this programmatically means it is not asking for the password. How can I Implement this feature?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be installing things in /System/Library at all. /System/Library is for the core system components provided by Apple; local & third-party additions, customizations, etc all belong in /Library (for system-wide resources and settings) or ~/Library (per-user resources and settings). See [Apple's filesystem docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW15) for more explanation.

Comment: @gordon davisson: thank you dude for your valuable information and the link.. suppose If I done this in my app whether apple will reject the app?

Comment: If you mean the Mac App Store, I'm pretty sure they would've rejected it.  [Apple's rules](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/approval/guidelines.html) forbid apps that install resources in shared locations (rule 2.15), escalate to root (rule 2.27), or violate the file system docs (rule 2.30).

Comment: @Gordon Davisson : thanks for the info... but I cant able to see this rule bcoz i am not memeber in that... If it is possible can you please copy the required rules in that and post that as a answer for this question. It will be very useful to me and all the members.

Comment: Since Apple keeps this restricted to developers, I'm a bit leery of publishing it openly in full.  But I found [someone who isn't so paranoid](http://wiki.factoryjoe.com/w/page/31720323/Apple%20App%20Store%20Review%20Guidelines), so you can read his copy.

Comment: thanks a million for this link....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to gain authorization to do a privileged operations from within your code.

The developer guide is available [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html).